# Timer App using React: setInterval is getting cleared after every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple timer app that will start to increment seconds on a button click. I am implementing this using react hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Timer() {

  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  const startTimer = () => {
    let timerID = setInterval(setSeconds((prevState) => prevState + 1), 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p> Seconds {seconds}</p>

      <button onClick={startTimer}> Start Timer </button>
    </>
  );
}


export default Timer;
```

The setInterval function is getting cleared after every render. Ideally it should continue to run until explicitly cleared. 
The seconds state increments only once for each click of start timer button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setInterval` method expects a function to call. You invoke `setSeconds`, which increment the seconds by 1 immediately, but `setInterval` can't call it again, since it's not a function. Wrap the expression with an arrow function:

```
() => setSeconds((prevState) => prevState + 1)
```

Example:

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React;

function Timer() {

  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  const startTimer = () => {
    let timerID = setInterval(
      () => setSeconds((prevState) => prevState + 1) // pass an arrow function that calls setSeconds
    , 100);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <p> Seconds {seconds}</p>

      <button onClick={startTimer}> Start Timer </button>
    </Fragment>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Timer />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Notes:

1. You should save `timerID` in a ref, so you can clear it
2. Clear the interval (and set seconds to 0) whenever the Start Timer button is clicked, so you won't have multiple running timers
3. Clear the interval when the component is unmounted with `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

1. `setInterval` need a function as a first parameter
2. To avoid memory leak, you need to clear previous interval

```js
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    
    function Timer() {
      const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
      const timerId = useRef(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        return () => stopTimer();
      }, []);
    
      const startTimer = () => {
        stopTimer();
        timerId.current = setInterval(
          () => setSeconds(prevState => prevState + 1),
          1000
        );
      };
    
      const stopTimer = () => {
        if (timerId.current != null) {
          clearInterval(timerId.current);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <p> Seconds {seconds}</p>
          <button onClick={startTimer}> Start Timer </button>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```